# I want to split with non alphabet without using import re

Tags: python, python-3.x

I already tried this by using `.isalpha()` and for or while loop. And I think this is quite messy... I might don't need to collect where I found the non-characters... Almost two days, I couldn't find a way. Can you give me some idea?

```
a = []
pos1 = 0
for pos in range(len(string)-1):
    if string[pos1].isalpha():
        pos1 += 1
a.append(pos1)
#I want to return list with string which splited with non alphabet
```

For example,

```
/a#apple;3^%$
```

should return

```
['/', 'a#', 'apple;3^%$']
```

If the code finds alphabet, then it collects previous characters, like that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fix your formatting and indentation. How does your code not work, exactly? The quality of the answers you get are proportional to the quality of your question (which is off to a good start, but a bit sloppy)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you're doing wrong in your code:

```
a = []
pos1 = 0
# Should use a better variable name, I don't know what's the purpose of this variable
for pos in range(len(string)-1):
    if string[pos1].isalpha(): # Shouldn't this be string[pos]?
        pos1 += 1 # You should append here
a.append(pos1) 
# you append a pos1 (which is a number) into a outside the loop
```

Here's the code that works:

```
string = '/a#apple;3^%$'

a = []
idx = 0
lastidx = 0
while idx < len(string): # loops through string
    while string[idx].isalpha(): # increment idx until we find a non-alphanumeric character
        idx += 1
        if idx >= len(string):break

    while not string[idx].isalpha(): # increment idx until we find an alphanumeric character
        idx += 1
        if idx >= len(string):break
    a.append(string[lastidx:idx]) # add the sliced string from lastidx to idx to a
    lastidx = idx # sets the last index to the current index
print(a)
```

Output:

```
['/', 'a#', 'apple;3^%$']
```

Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: Please explain what you did. A code dump is not much use by itself

Comment: @MadPhysicist Done.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll accept that, I know I'm a disappointment already.

Comment: Not really. Your solution is functional and well documented (now). The downvote was most likely for not adhering to the unwritten rules of the site. You fixed that part as soon as I explained that, so good work and I'm sure you'll have better luck in the future. Unfortunately most people don't come back to check on posts once they've voted, but don't let it bother you.

Comment: Have a +1 to sustain you.

Comment: Okay, I see what you meant.